# Why Jmeter Throughput Shaping Timer allows more requests than configured?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have configured Throughput Shaping Timer in my JMeter test to limit RPS to 50 while the Ultimate Thread Group is running 500 threads. I monitor the test using 'jp@gc-Transactions per Second' listener. I can see many instances where listener shows > 50 TPS. Not sure if I have configured my test wrongly.

My objective is to test my APIs with 50 concurrent hits with 500 sets of data which is in a CSV file. Thus I am using 'jp@gc-Ultimate Thread Group' to run 500 threads - each thread reads 1 data row from csv. To limit to 50 concurrent requests, I am using 'jp@gc-Throughput Shaping Timer' set to 50 rps. I have a beanshell, 1 HTTP Request and a post processor in the Test Fragment.

I am not expecting to see the spikes shown in image 3. Everything should be limited to 50 RPS.

I am using Jmeter 3.0 with Java 1.8 and Windows 7.

[image: jp@gc-Ultimate Thread Group]

[image: jp@gc-Throughput Shaping Timer]

[image: jp@gc-Transactions per Second]

Comment: See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096221/jmeter-throughput-shaping-timer-sending-more-requests-then-desired

Comment: I read it before. Its a different issue though.